# Jump / Position cursor in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I move the cursor to, say, position 25 on the current line?

Comment: Please reselect correct answer to one that uses "|"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In normal mode, use the pipe character:

```
25|
```

will move you to column 25 on the same line

Answer (score 18):

Enter:

```
024l
```

Explanation:

`0`: move the cursor to the first character on the current line
`24l`: move the cursor to the right 24 times (thereby arriving on the 25th column)